# How can I have a ControlTemplate that only creates a container for the default, unaltered visual tree of a control?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to figure out how to change a control's template to something that will make it held inside a `Grid`, like this:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="containedTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <!-- place templated control here -->
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

I of course want any of the inner control's properties to be synced automatically with the templated control.

Can this be done at all?

Here's an hypothetical example for a `TextBox` template:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="textTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Grid Background="Red">
        <TextBox Name="InnerTextBox" Margin="5,5,5,5"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Now if I did apply the template on a `TextBox` instance like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyTextProperty}" Template="{StaticResource textTemplate}"/>
```

... then the control would magically be a `Grid`, containing a `TextBox` with a few margins and whose `Text`'s property would be bound to `MyTextProperty` of whatever `DataContext` instance has been set:

```
<!-- runtime visual tree I'd like to be produced by the above XAML -->
<Grid Background="Red">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding MyTextProperty}" Margin="5,5,5,5"/>
</Grid>
```

If I had the following code:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding MyTextProperty}" Template="{StaticResource textTemplate}"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding MyOtherTextProperty}" Template="{StaticResource textTemplate}"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding YetAnotherTextProperty}" Template="{StaticResource textTemplate}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

The resulting tree would be this:

```
<!-- runtime visual tree I'd like to be produced by the above XAML -->
<StackPanel>
    <Grid Background="Red">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding MyTextProperty}" Margin="5,5,5,5"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Background="Red">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding MyOtherTextProperty}" Margin="5,5,5,5"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Background="Red">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding YetAnotherTextProperty}" Margin="5,5,5,5"/>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

In these examples you can see that the `TextBox`'s `Text` property is correctly propagated down to the "inner" `TextBox` instance. The control's default visual tree is also preserved (borders, typing area, etc.).

I'm aware of template parts but as I said I'm trying to find a global approach here, and I **DO NOT** want to change the control's appearance; only put it inside a container.

Comment: still your question is not clear

Comment: @safi I changed the title. Is is any better?

Comment: explain this "that only creates a container for the default"

Comment: @safi I mean that I don't want to recreate the whole visual tree for a control, I just want it *exactly as it is* by default, but contained inside another control as its content. I added an example, maybe it will help further clear things up.

Answer (score 1):

frankly, this question exhausted me, i have this only answer but not convince me a lot.

first you should create multi `ControlTemplates` for each control that you want to set your template then create this class

```
public class ControlTemplateConverter
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsEnabledProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsEnabled", typeof(bool), typeof(ControlTemplateConverter), new UIPropertyMetadata(false, IsEnabledChanged));

    private static void IsEnabledChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ControlTemplate t;
        if (d == null) return;
        if (d is TextBlock)
            t = App.Current.FindResource("TextBoxTemplate") as ControlTemplate;
        else if (d is CheckBox)
            t = App.Current.FindResource("CheckBoxTemplate") as ControlTemplate;
        // and So On

        (d as Control).Template = t;
    }

    public static bool GetIsEnabled(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsEnabledProperty);
    }
    public static void SetIsEnabled(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsEnabledProperty, value);
    }
}
```

and your control should like this:

```
<TextBox local:ControlTemplateConverter.IsEnabled="True"></TextBox>
<CheckBox local:ControlTemplateConverter.IsEnabled="True"></CheckBox>
```

Comment: It seems I can't make my question clear enough (english isn't my main language). I do not need an ability to dynamically create a template, I only want to know how I can create a template for a control that will present it contained inside a panel-type control while keeping its properties in sync.

Comment: correct me if wrong.
you want to set something to Grid or whatever panel, so every control inside it should put inside grid, or inside template that you defiened

Comment: Hold on, I'll create another example.

Comment: There, have a look. I'm afraid I can't explain it any further though.